# liveScroll appended page refresh on selecting row Primefaces dataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I think i found a bug with livescroll in dataTable in Primefaces 6.1.

I have command link in second column that is saving row/rownumber to variables and calling method to save a file. It works on first 10 elements (size of page), but dont work on any other element that is appended by live pagination - instead something happens to invoke load with first set to 0. I dont see any errors in browser console or tomcat console. On my main project also page is losing all css elements, only text stays, but it could be liferay 6.2 issue.

If i disable liveScroll by replacing

```
scrollRows="10" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="90%" scrollable="true"
```

with

```
paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink}" paginator="true"
```

everything works. I have run out of ideas how to debug and fix it, any suggestions?

xhtml datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="live" value="#{LiveLazyModel}" rows="10" lazy="true"
               scrollRows="10" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="90%" scrollable="true"
               style="width: 1000px">
     <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{live.id}" id="idlive"/>
     </p:column>
     <p:column headerText=".txt" style="width: 80px" exportable="false">
        <h:commandLink>
           <h:outputText value="download"/>
           <f:param name="liveId" value="#{live.id}" />
           <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{live}" target="#{LiveLazyModel.selectedRow}"/>
           <p:fileDownload value="#{LiveLazyModel.liveStreamedContent}"/>
        </h:commandLink>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "LiveLazyModel")
@ViewScoped
public class LiveLazyModel extends LazyDataModel {

    private Live selectedRow;

    @Override
    public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) {
        List list = addToList(first, pageSize);
        this.setRowCount(100);
        this.setPageSize(pageSize);
        return list;
    }

    private List addToList(int first, int pageSize) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for (Integer i = first; i < first + pageSize; i++) {
            list.add(new Live(i));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public StreamedContent getliveStreamedContent()  throws IOException {
        String idFrom = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("liveId");
        if(selectedRow != null){
            InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(selectedRow.id + (Double.toString(Math.random()).substring(1)));
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(targetStream, "txt", "idLiveFromSelectedRow" + selectedRow.id + ".txt");
        }
        if (idFrom != null) {
            InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(idFrom + (Double.toString(Math.random()).substring(1)));
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(targetStream, "txt", "idLiveFromFacesContext" + idFrom + ".txt");
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("liveId is null & selectedRow is null  ");
    }

    public void setSelectedRow(Live selectedRow) {
        this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    }
}
```

Working barebone code could be found on: 
   https://github.com/TomaszKocinski/jsfPFLiveScrollBugPagination

to run it: mvn tomcat7:run should be enough, localhost:9966/live